# Emit Events from hooks like on_initialize()

Tags: pallet, events

Is it okay to emit event from hooks like `on_initialize()`?
For example, I have ~1000 items in storage and in a loop in `on_initialize()` I want to emit an event if certain process is completed, then is it fine?
Also, what is more efficient:

a) emit a burst of 1000 events, or

b) combine events information in a large `Vec<>` and then send it wrapping in an event?

Comment: We actually face the same issue https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/pull/1203/files#r906009860

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to emit events from `on_initialize`/`on_finalize`. These events get tagged with a different phase. Normally events have phase `ApplyExtrinsic(ext_id)` but here they get `Initialization` and `Finalization` respectively. Just something to look out for in the frontend.

> Also what is more efficient a) emit burst of 1000 events or b) combine events information in a large Vec<> and then send it wrapping in an event?

Efficient in what way? Events are a vector in storage to which each new one is appended.
I would probably just go with the standard approach of *one event per event* to keep the code simple, but I don't think there is a general downside of large events.