# Emitting errors from hooks like on_initialize()

Tags: pallet

A similar question exists here : [Emit Events from hooks like on_initialize()](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/emit-events-from-hooks-like-on-initialize)

If we are performing fallible operations on pallet hooks like `on_initialize` and let's say we want to notify the frontend (e.g. polkadot-js), is there a way to *emit* errors in the same fashion as `Self::deposit_event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_initialize` must be infallible by definition.
Yes you can use Events to emit progress of failure from inside there. I don't think its hacky; the Scheduler does this when its unable to find a preimage. The MessageQueue pallet also does this while processing messages.
There is no other way to emit information here though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not the correct approach to design. Consider whether it's really necessary to include it in the `on_initialize` function.

However, you are able to deposit an event called `XXXError(error_info)` in the `on_initialize` function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it might be incorrect?

Comment: Due to some "lacking" of the existing `Error` system, there is a need to utilize the `Event` system as a replacement. However, this approach may seem counterintuitive for developers and users.